# Android boot loop after fresh install

Tags: nexus-4, factory-reset, boot-loop, twrp

Phone: Nexus 4 with the latest android 5.1.1. 
Accidentally I broke my screen and turned off my phone. After a month my screen was replaced and then I got stuck in the boot loop at the start.

I've made factory reset in both android recovery and TWRP recovery.

I've tried to install popular ROMs (Chroma) and google factory images: all from the latest LMY48M to the old ones. Installation was OK, but after install I have a boot loop (flying dots, or rotating circles, etc - I have been waiting for hours).
I made it to start the system - only with the oldest factory image: JDQ39 (4.2.2)

After android started and some configuration made (wifi, google account), after some time, phone tells me about system update 4.3. I agreed and got stuck in the boot loop again.

I know that there are tons of `stuck in boot loop` questions, but usually solution is to clean cache, factory reset, or reinstall. And I have boot loop stucking after factory reset and fresh install. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

I think, I can live with 4.2.2, but maybe it's possible to get 5.1 working back?

P.S. All installations (adb sideload of ROMs or ./flash-all.sh for factory images) where finished successfully. The only error I got was `unable to mount /usb-otg` in TWRP while factory reset (anyway it said that reset was done). But I think it's not the reason, isn't it?

**Update:**
I've tried all factory builds from [official source](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en). They come with script that manually run `fastboot` to flash images:

```
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-mako-makoz30f.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
sleep 5
fastboot flash radio radio-mako-m9615a-cefwmazm-2.0.1701.07.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
sleep 5
fastboot -w update image-occam-lmy48m.zip
```

It always finished with success - no errors. But after restart - boot loop freezes.
Also, I've always made a factory reset before flashing factory images. I've tried both via original recovery.img and via TWRP (with Dalvik cache)

**Update2:**
[Here is](https://gist.github.com/larrycinnabar/474cc93527baf3913aa8) my `adb logcat` on start of working 4.2.2. I've managed to get it only after turning on `USB debugging`. My question is - will the `USB debugging` mode reset after wiping data? I want to try install 5.1.1 factory image again and to collect `adb logcat` data. But if USB debugging option is resetted, then I will have no result again.

Comment: Can you run `adb logcat` during boot and post the output somewhere? To get adb to work during boot, you may need to copy the contents of the file `<your home folder>/.android/adbkey.pub` to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` (create it if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Do I need to run `adb logcat` exactly when I am in a stuck loop boot? When loop boot was stucked, I have no devices in `adb devices`

Comment: Ah. That's odd. Are you sure it doesn't flash back to the Google screen every so often? If you do manage to get it to work, the timing of the `adb logcat` shouldn't matter. Just upload the output somewhere and it should be reasonably helpful.

Comment: @keepcalm, no, it doesn't flash back to the Google screen every so ofter. Just spinning the dots. I've run `adb logcat` before I started the smartphone. It says: `- waiting for device -`. Then I try to boot smartphone and nothing happens, still waiting for device. But adb connection worked for me when I made `adb sideload` from twrp

Comment: Ah. You might need to install drivers (assuming you're on Windows). [This one](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver) should work.

Comment: Did you flash the latest bootloader and radio images? I suggest that you flash the latest factory image with radio,bootloader and everything manually.

Comment: @keepcalm, I'm on Ubuntu. I've installed adb 1.0.32, because at first, 1.0.31 version from repo didn't allow to sideload. With adb 1.0.32 I can get adb connection but only in Recovery Mode.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury, I've installed factory images with ./flash-all.sh script. It flashes everything - radio, bootloader, recovery and system. Then I've tried custom builds (ROMs - `adb sideload filename.zip`) and after installing the same effect again. I had different types of boot loops (circles, dots, chroma-logo) but it was always stucked

Comment: @Evghenii, have you tried running `adb` as root - like `sudo adb devices`. Alternatively, you can try following the steps in [this](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/UDEV) article.

Comment: @keepcalm, progress has been made! I've turned on 'USB Debugging' and now I see a huge logcat while starting. Is this logcat useful - I mean I'm on 4.2.2 now, and there is no bootloop stucking. Or I need to get that log exactly when I get bootloop stucking (for 4.3+)? If I make a factory reset and install 5.1.1 one more time, then usb debugging option will be resetted, won't it?

Comment: Yes. Factory resetting clears the USB debugging flag

Comment: The bootloop needs to have happened on the boot you're collecting info for. I think you should be able to enable ADB on first boot by editing `/system/build.prop` to contain the lines ```persist.service.adb.enable=1<new line>                                                
persist.service.debuggable=1<new line>
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb```

Comment: @keepcalm, Am I understanding correct the steps I need to do: 1) Another factory reset, 2) fastboot 5.1.1 factory image, 3) fastboot twrp. 4) in twrp mount /system folder and edit file `build.prop` on my computer. 5) `adb logcat` and start booting. 6) collecting results of logcat

Comment: @keepcalm, Also, I've made updated of my post - there is a link to gist with my logcat (on working 4.2.2, but maybe it will also help)

Comment: @Evghenii yep - if you edit build.prop to contain those lines, and put `~/.android/adbkey.pub` in `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`, you should be able to get a logcat on first boot. Your 4.2.2 logcat isn't much use I'm afraid, but 5.1.1 might be worth a shot.

Comment: @keepcalm, ok, thanks. I think I will try this on my weekend and report here

Comment: @LarryCinnabar I'm in a very similar predicament now.  If you see this comment, I'd be interested to know how the situation progressed.

Answer (score 1):

Do a factory image flash using fastboot,taking special care to update the partition data,bootloader and radio images. Partition data means the ebr/mbr/preloader partitions. The manual flash implies that you must flash each partition manually, just so that you are sure that everything was flashed correctly, even if the script executed without errors.This should resolve the issue. If it doesn't, maybe a flash using Qualcomm MSMDownloader will work. It would help if you could upload the names of the images in the factory image archive, so that I can find out which partitions may be causing the problem

Comment: Can you please, be more specific about `update the partition data`? I've updated my post, and showed how I've tried to do a factory image flash